VScode fails to make subolder
I am working in a beginner MERN stack project
I am using VS code.
when I make folder(M) and then a sub-folder(a) it's okay
then I try to subfolder inside folder(M) as sub-folder(b)
but it's make like folder(M) -> sub-folder(a) -> sub-folder(b)
my requirement

but in actual VS code


VsCode inlines the tree structure when folders are empty. You have make sure you are really selecting the parent folder when creating a second child folder. If you have selected child folder when creating new folder then you'll end up creating a grand child folder.
I'll recommend you to checkout this answer to disable compact folders:  Turn off visual studio code inline parent/child folder display


I though I was choosing parent folder before creating, but not I understood I was actually selecting subfolder.
thank you very much for the demo
